# Updating Facebook User Data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, facebook-graph-api, passport-facebook

I'm trying to found a way to update : "profile._json.friends.data" everytime the user logs in (because it only picks up and saves the friends list on the DB once at the first login).

I heard that we can use :

findOneAndUpdate
or Facebook Graph API (to avoid having to update)

but I'm not sure how I can do this or if I started the right way...

I'm using passport-facebook, mongodb/mongoose

I hope it will be understandable enough, don't hesitate if you have a better way to do it !

Thank you in advance !

```
// Passport configuration =====================================================
// used to serialize the user for the session
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});
// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
app.use(function(req, res, next){
   res.locals.currentUser = req.user; 
   next();
});
// =========================================================================
// FACEBOOK ================================================================
// =========================================================================
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    // pull in our app id and secret from our auth.js file
    clientID        : configAuth.facebookAuth.clientID,
    clientSecret    : configAuth.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
    callbackURL     : configAuth.facebookAuth.callbackURL,
    profileFields   : configAuth.facebookAuth.profileFields
},
// facebook will send back the token and profile
function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    // asynchronous
    process.nextTick(function() {
        // find the user in the database based on their facebook id
        User.findOne({ 'facebook.id' : profile.id }, function(err, user) {
            // if there is an error, stop everything and return that
            // ie an error connecting to the database
            if (err)
                return done(err);
            // if the user is found, then log them in
            if (user) {
                return done(null, user); // user found, return that user
            } else {
                // if there is no user found with that facebook id, create them
                var newUser            = new User();
                // set all of the facebook information in our user model
                newUser.facebook.id    = profile.id; // set the users facebook id                   
                newUser.facebook.token = token; // we will save the token that facebook provides to the user                    
                newUser.facebook.name  = profile.displayName; // pull name from profile displayName
                profile.emails ? newUser.facebook.email = profile.emails[0].value : newUser.facebook.email = "no email"; // if email isn't released from fb then set to "no email"
                profile.photos ? newUser.facebook.picture = profile.photos[0].value : '/img/faces/unknown-user-pic.jpg';
                newUser.facebook.gender = profile.gender;
                newUser.facebook.friends = profile._json.friends.data;
                // save our user to the database
                newUser.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        throw err;
                    // if successful, return the new user
                    return done(null, newUser);
                });
            }
        });
    });
}));
app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    res.render('profile.ejs', {
        user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
    });
});
// =====================================
// HOME PAGE ===========================
// =====================================
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('landing'); // load the index.ejs file
});
// route for showing the profile page
app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    res.render('profile', {
        user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
    });
});
// =====================================
// FACEBOOK ROUTES =====================
// =====================================
// route for facebook authentication and login
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { authType: 'rerequest', scope : ['email', 'user_friends'] }));
// handle the callback after facebook has authenticated the user
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        successRedirect : '/profile',
        failureRedirect : '/'
    }));
// route for logging out
app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localized guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I read your link, I agree with that, but it does not advance me more in my way of formulating my question. Maybe I need to precise that I'm not asking people to make this for me, 
I just want some advice on whether I'm on track with what I found or not, I think I need to rework this part : // if the user is found, then log them in
            if (user) {
                return done(null, user); // user found, return that user
            } 
but I'm not sure, maybe I'm completely wrong...

Comment: Okay, so my initial heuristic analysis was incorrect. Your question looks to be more of a [where to start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367) question, which is similarly a common source of off-topic questions.

Comment: No, I think you were right but I forgot to mention some important points

Comment: Also, while you're at it, [it might help if you improved the formatting some, so it's a little easier to follow](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: (Note: as for the question itself, I'm not intimately familiar with Facebook's Graph API, so I couldn't really help you on that front. I'm just helping you get your question in a way that attracts more answers by other people.)

Comment: Yes I understand, thanks again for helping me rephrase my question ! I'll edit it with more informations !